# MS Excel create virtual column to use in formula

Tags: excel, formula

I want to do something similar to summing 1/x from 1 to 100 without creating an extra column to help with the calculation. I want my first column to be the numbers 1 through 100. And I want a cell to show the sum of 1/x where x is each cell in the first column. Currently the only way I can think to do this is to create a second column to do 1/x for each individual cell then sum the second column. Is there any solution to doing this without having to create the second column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this "array formula"

=SUM(1/A1:A100)

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

....or avoid array entry by using SUMPRODUCT

=SUMPRODUCT(1/A1:A100)

both versions assume you don't have zeroes (or blanks) in A1:A100

if you might have zeroes or blanks then use this array formula

=SUM(IF(A1:A100,1/A1:A100))

Answer (score 2):

if you mean `1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/100`, use following [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) (entered by Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter):

```
=sum(1/row(A1:A100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array formula as below:

```
{=SUM(1/A1:A100)}
```

where A1:A100 contains 1 to 100

You create the array formula bu typing the formula as `=SUM(1/A1:A100)` and then pressing Control-Shift-Enter.

If you do it correctly the formula then shows up with the curly brackets {} but you don't enter the curly brackets yourself.